# Solving an integral while looking for probability density of range in 3-D from Normal distributed RV.

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, density-function, bessel-functions, gaussian-integral

I'm trying to get the probability density function of the range from Gaussian distributed $\mathrm{\bar{y}} = [x,y,z]$ coordinates (covariance matrix identity). I know,

\begin{align}
x &= r.cos(\alpha)cos(\theta)\\
y &= r.cos(\alpha)sin(\theta)\\
z &= r.sin(\alpha)
\end{align}

where $r$ is the range, $\theta$ azimuth and $\alpha$ is the elevation.

I transformed the Gaussian distribution and arrived at the following joint distribution in spherical coordinates,
\begin{align}
p(r,\theta,\alpha) = \frac{r^2cos(\alpha)}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \exp(-1/2 (r^2 + \mu^T\mu))\exp(r\mu^T\beta)
\end{align}

where $\mu$ is the mean of Gaussian distributed variables, and $\beta$ is,
\begin{align}
\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
         cos(\alpha)cos(\theta)\\
         cos(\alpha)sin(\theta)\\
         sin(\alpha)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Then I marginalized $\theta$ and $\alpha$ to get the integral,
\begin{align}
p(r) = \frac{r^2}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \exp(-1/2 (r^2 + \mu^T\mu)) \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} cos(\alpha)\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(r\mu^T\beta)d\theta d\alpha
\end{align}

Using $\mu^T = [a,b,c]$, the inner integral can be solved. Hence
\begin{align}
p(r) = \frac{r^2cos(\alpha)}{(2\pi)^{3/2}} \exp(-1/2 (r^2 + \mu^T\mu)) \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} cos(\alpha) \exp(rcsin(\alpha)) \mathrm{I}_0(r\sqrt{a^2+b^2}cos(\alpha)) d\alpha
\end{align}
Where $\mathrm{I}_0(.)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and zeroth order.
There shouldn't be any mistakes thus far but I cannot seem to make any progress now. Is there a general form of such integral,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} cos(\alpha) \exp(rcsin(\alpha)) \mathrm{I}_0(r\sqrt{a^2+b^2}cos(\alpha)) d\alpha
\end{align}

Later on I would probably also have to calculate the integral,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} cos^2(\alpha) \exp(rcsin(\alpha)) \mathrm{I}_1(r\sqrt{a^2+b^2}cos(\alpha)) d\alpha
\end{align}

Notice the order of modified Bessel function has increased.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the range $r$ just $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ with $x,y,z$ being three independent  standard normal random variables? If so, there is an easier calculation since $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a $\chi^2$ random variable with three degrees of freedom whose pdf you can look up, and then all you need to do is find the pdf of the square root of this random variable for which again, there is a canned formula that you can use to plug-and-chug,

Comment: I think you're right. My approach is cumbersome, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ should have a non-central $\chi$ distribution. Thanks for pointing out.